# Naive question on how to type-annotated my ocaml prog. in emacs

Tags: emacs, types, annotations, ocaml, tuareg

I heard we can annotate ocaml prog. by their types. An older thread in the forum suggested using ocaml mode of 
http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/poly/emacs/index.html

I have been using Tuareg mode, in which it suggested using "c-c c-t" to retrieve types, cf. this piece of codes in tuareg.el

```
 (when tuareg-with-caml-mode-p
      ;; Trigger caml-types
      (define-key map [?\C-c ?\C-t] 'caml-types-show-type)
      ;; To prevent misbehavior in case of error during exploration.
      (define-key map [(control mouse-2)] 'caml-types-mouse-ignore)
      (define-key map [(control down-mouse-2)] 'caml-types-explore)
```

I got "c-c c-t" undefined although everything seems to be well configured.

Here is the .emacs file

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cons '("\\.ml[iyl]?$" .  caml-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(autoload 'caml-mode "ocaml" 
  "Major mode for editing Caml code." t)

(autoload 'camldebug "camldebug" 
  "Call the camldebugger on FILE" t)

;; adjust paths for emacs source code
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/my-emacs-config/caml-mode")

;; adjust paths for emacs ocaml info sources
(require 'info)
(add-to-list 'Info-directory-list "~/my-emacs-config/caml-mode")
```

Here is the files in caml-mode (which contains ocaml.el)

```
bash-3.2$ ls ~/my-emacs-config/caml-mode/
caml-compat.el  caml-emacs.el   caml-font.el    caml-help.el    caml-hilit.el   caml-types.el   caml.el     camldebug.el    inf-caml.el ocaml.el
```

I did the following

--write an factorial func. in ocaml, called "annot.ml"

```
let rec f n = 
if n = 1 then 0 else n * f(n-1)
```

--ocamlc -annot annot.ml

--open annot.ml by emacs and press "c-c c-t" while the cursor is under "n"

I got in the minibuffer of emacs

```
c-c c-t undefined
```

Conclusion, I still cannot retrieve types. Why??? Thank you for your ideas.

More info: when I try M-x caml-[tab] I get the following list, which does not contain caml-types-show-types

```
Possible completions are:
caml-mode              camldebug
camldebug-backtrace        camldebug-break
camldebug-close            camldebug-complete
camldebug-delete           camldebug-display-frame
camldebug-down             camldebug-finish
camldebug-goto             camldebug-kill
camldebug-last             camldebug-mode
camldebug-next             camldebug-open
camldebug-print            camldebug-refresh
camldebug-reverse          camldebug-run
camldebug-step             camldebug-up
```

Comment: Can you run the command bound to `C-C C-t` directly? [`M-x caml-types-show-type`]

Answer (score 1):

You're autoloading `caml-mode` from `ocaml.el` or `ocaml.elc`. But there is no such file! The official Caml mode is in a file called `caml.el`, and Tuareg mode is in a file called `tuareg.el`. This explains why opening your `.ml` file doesn't put you in Ocaml mode and doesn't load the Caml support. Change your autoload to either this to use the official mode

```
(autoload 'caml-mode "caml" 
  "Major mode for editing Caml code." t)
```

or this to use Tuareg mode

```
(autoload 'caml-mode "tuareg" 
  "Major mode for editing Caml code." t)
```

Comment: But it hardly loads the stuff from `tuareg.el` you were asking about.